# Dask is slow when grouping by multiple columns and then aggregating

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have a dataframe with columns `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. All datatypes are ints.

I have a dask-cluster available with 10 workers, 20 cores and 20 GB of RAM.

I would like to group the dataframe by a and b and sum d within the groups.

```
f = 's3://some_s3_bucket/some_file.csv_*.csv.gz'

cols = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd' ]

df = dd.read_csv(f, encoding='latin-1',  compression='gzip', header=None, names =cols, blocksize=None) 

df_pers = client.persist(df)
```

Then I do

```
df_agg_graph = df_pers.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].sum()
df_agg = df_agg_graph.compute()
```

and the result takes forever to compute.

When I go

```
f_agg_graph = df_pers.groupby(['a'])['c'].sum()
```

i.e. I focus on `a` only everything works quick and as expected.

Do you have an idea what could be the issue here?

I believe I want to distribute the data by `a` and then group by `a` and `b`, is this correct? However, even if I do `df = df.set_index('a')` before persisting above, things do not get better.

Many thanks
c

Comment: As with most performance problems, I recommend taking a look at the dashboard.  http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html (sorry for the non-informative answer)

Comment: Hi @MRocklin many thanks. Can you give me some hints as to what to look out for/ what I could report here for questions. I do not get much from the Dashboard unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, I did get it to work by scaling the workers in the cluster (probably a memory issue). But, do you know how I could have detected this from the dashboard? The memory on the workers did not seem to be fully consumed in the previous configuration.